# why does order matter in this escaped characters class in sed?

Tags: regex, sed

This works as expected:

```
>echo -= | sed 's/[\=\-]//g'
>
```

But this does not:

```
>echo -= | sed 's/[\-\=]//g'
>-
```

Why??

Comment: thank you Etan and others - I just assumed, that since I have to escape - and = in a regex but outside of range, then I have to do that too, inside the range in a regex

Comment: Hm? You don't need to escape `-` and `=` outside of a class either. `printf '-=foo=-\n' | sed 's/-=//'` -> `foo=-`.

Comment: well I guess not.  Thank you.  I think I need some sleep :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a character class the `-` can be used to create a range (e.g. `[A-Z]` which is all character from `A` to `Z` and not the three characters `A`, `-`, and `Z`).

As such when you write `[\-\=]` that is being seen as the range from `\` to `\=` (I don't think escaping the `=` is meaningful here).

But when you write `[\=\-]` the range interpretation is not possible because the terminating `]` of the class cannot be the end of the range.

Similarly if you wrote `[-\=]` you would not have a range interpretation of that class.

As I said though I don't think escaping either of these characters is meaningful though and is, in fact, what triggered this problem as `[-=]` works the same and doesn't have the range issue.

In a similar fashion, using `^` at the start of a character class negates the class so if you want a literal `^` in a class it needs to *not* be the first character in the class.

Comment: Is there a way to escape the `-` even if it’s somewhere in the middle?

Comment: @Etan wait Etan, but that's why I am escaping the darn thing - to avoid it being interpreted as a range indicator

Comment: @MarkGaleck: The backslash doesn't have any particular meaning inside `[]` in a regex. It just means backslash. So `[\=\-]` is a character class that contains *three* characters: backslash, equals, and hyphen.

Comment: Yeah, you don't "escape" things inside a character class (unfortunately).

Comment: @Xufox Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @GregHewgill Except for escaping a `]`, I’d assume. But it doesn’t work either…

Comment: @Xufox Nope. You stick it at the start or end of the class. So either `[]A-Z]` or `[A-Z]]` since an empty class isn't allowed and neither is a lone `]`. Same for `[`.

Comment: Fortunately, we don’t have to worry about character classes inside character classes…

Comment: @Xufox But if you need *both* `[` **and** `]` in the same class then (at least with the sed I have here) you can't use `[[A-Z]]` you need to use `[]A-Z[]`

Comment: Alright, sed works a bit differently from JavaScript in that regard…

Comment: That is funny. In a range in sed, instead of escaping things, you rearrange them so they cannot have the escaped meaning.

Comment: Yes, this is all a bit engine specific I think. Though most of this should be fairly portable I would expect.

Comment: Please read [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for details as to why you can't escape things. It seems like it's a GNU/POSIX thing... And I quote

*The POSIX and GNU flavors are an exception. They treat backslashes in character classes as literal characters. So with these flavors, you can't escape anything in character classes.*

Comment: @Xufox Right. `sed` is a very old regexp engine, it predates things like PCRE, which allows escaping instead of depending on ordering.